# FOS user error with add new user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Today i tried to create a new user and got an error:

> General error: 1364 Field 'expired' doesn't have a default value

This error happened when i tried to add new user to fos user table. Maybe this error from new update of fos user bundle version. How can i fix that?
Here is my code:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
      $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
      $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $language = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Language')->findOneBy(['code' => $request->getLocale()]);
      $user->setLanguage($language);
      $user->addRole('ROLE_FARMER');

      $level = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Level')->find($request->request->get('fos_user_registration_form')['level']);
      $user->getClient()->setLevel($level);
      $user->getClient()->setUser($user);

      try {
          $userManager->updateUser($user);

          $team = new Team();
          $team->setClient($user->getClient());
          $team->setUser($user);
          $em->persist($team);
          $em->flush();
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
          $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
          $errorForm = $this->showErrors($form, $errorMessage);

          return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $errorForm->createView(),
            ));
        }

      if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
          $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
          $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
      }

      $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

      return $response;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is because of the FOSUserBundle version update.

Fields **expired** and **credentialsExpired** are removed.

More details on:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/4ea37a5f7ef423b03b0619fc7cbe0d1ae436edff

Try to update your database schema, and then try again to register user.
It should work :)